# How should I measure the oxygen dispersed during photosynthesis in pondweeds?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, lab-techniques, photosynthesis

I am to conduct a lab investigating how different wavelengths of light affects photosynthesis in Egeria pondweeds.

The idea is to put color filters on light bulbs and shine them on the pondweed in a sodium hydrogen carbonate solution. Then to measure the oxygen, I have an oxygen sensor which measures dissolved oxygen (mg/L).

Now, what I have a trouble with is if measuring the dissolved oxygen is the right way to measure the rate of photosynthesis depending on color of light? Will it work?

Comment: One experiment I saw online, was that during 5 minutes you measure the oxygen dispersed, and it will show you the mg/L depending on time.

Comment: That solution might just kill the plants.

Comment: Why not do it in a standardised pondwater, unless you don't mind the results being for only that sodium bicarb solution?

Comment: A couple thoughts.  The plant is undergoing cellular respiration too, so I am not sure that there will be a net oxygen out.  I assume that the sodium hudrogen carbonate is going to provide a source of carbon dioxide to a closed system, but even then the plant will release carbon dioxide from respiration from sugar that it has made and burned.

Comment: Is the atmosphere sealed and airtight?  You could possibly have Sodium Hydrogen Carbonate in a water reservoir in the container, but not in the water that the pondweeds are growing in.

Comment: what margin of error is acceptable in the result of your tests,light bulbs and filters might not be the best way to produce the different parts of the electromagnetic spectrum you want(i guess you want to keep the energy level fixed so only the color changes).different LED`s might be a better solution for your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Bubble formation might be easier to measure than oxygen concentration. Bubbles can be measured optically Or acoustically.

A sealed container with a little carbon dioxide gas might work.

See below article.

“Acoustic effects during photosynthesis of aquatic plants enable new research opportunities”

Helmut G. Kratochvil and Michael Pollirer
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5349586/

Comment: You can also work out via displacement - pondweed underneath an inverted container, traps bubbles that escape (gentle agitation might help) and measure volume .

Answer (score -1):

The experiment means anything only if different "colors" (wavelengths of light) affect the rate of photosynthesis. A good experiment requires that you "keep everything same/identical*, to the extent possible, save the *color* of the light the plants are exposed to. If you detect any changes in the concentration of oxygen, you can plot the *color of light* to the *oxygen concentration*.

Photosynthesis is a chemical reaction:
$6CO_2 + 6H_2O \rightarrow C_6H_{12}O_6 + 6O_2$

At the very least, the concentration of $CO_2$ and amount of $H_2O$ must be constant for different colors, as they can alter the rate of photosynthesis, and are therefore *confounding factors*.